# Application Insights duplicated dependency logs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights configured for a production webapp. The nuget packages are installed, AppInsights.config and Web.config are configured (default configuration) and I don't have any changes in the codebase except setting the instrumentation key dynamically. 
Is it normal to see the same dependency logged multiple times and why is it happening? And by "multipe times" I mean 15-20.

Example:
[image]

SQL Profiler shows only 1 SQL query so the problem is only with the logging.
<strike>The same happens with (AJAX) dependencies as well.</strike> Any idea what could be the source of the problem?

EDIT:
The data from analytics.applicationinsights.io shows that only the timestamps are different:
[image]

EDIT2:
https://pastebin.com/CAUQTGVi

```
    {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.INSTKEY.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-09-18T07:17:08.9288418Z","iKey":"INST-KEY","tags":{"ai.operation.parentId":"|cVw20.519d7d1f_","ai.session.id":"9U54e","ai.operation.id":"cVw20","ai.operation.name":"POST OrderItemTileBrowser/List","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"PC-JOHNDOE.Company.local","ai.user.id":"J9s5n","ai.internal.nodeName":"PC-JOHNDOE.Company.local","ai.user.authUserId":"iTos","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.4.0-32470"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"SQL\\PRODUCTION | SomeDatabaseName","id":"|2piZlu5+k1o=.519d7d46_","duration":"00:00:00.0012586","success":true,"type":"SQL","target":"SQL\\PRODUCTION | SomeDatabaseName","properties":{"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.0')"}}}}
    {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.INSTKEY.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-09-18T07:17:08.9308469Z","iKey":"INST-KEY","tags":{"ai.operation.parentId":"|cVw20.519d7d1f_","ai.session.id":"9U54e","ai.operation.id":"cVw20","ai.operation.name":"POST OrderItemTileBrowser/List","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"PC-JOHNDOE.Company.local","ai.user.id":"J9s5n","ai.internal.nodeName":"PC-JOHNDOE.Company.local","ai.user.authUserId":"iTos","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.4.0-32470"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"SQL\\PRODUCTION | SomeDatabaseName","id":"|kI7U4BuILOs=.519d7d47_","duration":"00:00:00.0018574","success":true,"type":"SQL","target":"SQL\\PRODUCTION | SomeDatabaseName","properties":{"_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.0')"}}}}
...
```

The data sent to AI servers (captured using Fiddler, some sensitive info replaced with dummy placeholders)

The only related topic I found (which does not mention duplication of logged items), and definitely does not answer my question nor gives me an acceptable solution: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/97d9f0b0-9d1e-4261-b80f-c7b7f07ecfe2/telemetry-throttling-how-can-i-cut-back-on-telemetry-events-disable-dependancy-events?forum=ApplicationInsights

Comment: interestingly, some have a duration of 0 and some have a duration of 1, so there's at least 2 different detected things there.  do you only have 1 user?  it would be odd for ajax dependencies to be doubled unless you've somehow initialized appinsights multiple times in the same browser page?  and those dependencies are coming from a browser, and these are coming from a backend instance.  if you look at the individual details of the events, or use an analytics query to verify, are they really exactly the same?  or do you have a bunch of users causing the same things to occur at the same time?

Comment: The AJAX duplicates were observed on production environment so it is indeed possible that multiple users were on the same page. Additionally I could not reproduce it with my test scenario. I'm editing my original question to remove the AJAX part. 
My real problem are the SQL dependencies. The user is only one for sure (me -  reproduced it on our test environment). I used analytics query and updated the original question with a screenshot. The only difference is the timestamp.

Comment: if the timestamps are different, then itemId should also be different, and those are distinctly reported items.  I don't see every item the same number of times (which would imply to me multiple copies of the dependency collector running).  If you use fiddler while in your local environment, do you see duplicate telemetry *sent*?

Comment: also, it might be worth posting this at the GitHub repo where this code is as an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server

Comment: what generates your sql queries?  is it a middle layer or entity framework or anything?  there might be something turning property accessors into queries?

Comment: I used Fiddler as you suggested. This is what the AI SDK sends: https://pastebin.com/CAUQTGVi It appears the dependencies are logged multiple times, so they are sent multiple times to AI servers. About the query generation, I am using NHibernate but SQL Server profiler shows only a single SQL query so that shouldn't be the case. I will also post the issue to AI GitHub repository.

Comment: given that the sdk outputs have "rddf:2.4.0-32470" as the sdk that generated them, they were detected and sent by the dependency collector: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/tree/develop/Src/DependencyCollector .  is there any chance that that collector is configured multiple times (like in code AND in a web.config file?)